# Celery chain tasks

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

Context:

**tasks.py**

```
def chunkify(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]

@task
def swarm_restart(procs):
   chunks = chunkify(procs, 4)
    res = chain(
        group_restart.s(( [ (proc.name, proc.host.name) for proc in chunks[0] ] )),
        group_restart.s(( [ (proc.name, proc.host.name) for proc in chunks[1] ] )),
        group_restart.s(( [ (proc.name, proc.host.name) for proc in chunks[2] ] )),
        group_restart.s(( [ (proc.name, proc.host.name) for proc in chunks[3] ] )),
    )()

@ task
def group_restart(procs):
    # this task runs only once, seems to be called just 1 time
    res = group( proc_restart.s(proc[0], proc[1]) for proc in procs ).apply_async()

@ task
def proc_restart(proc_name, hostname):
    # This method works, tested several times
    proc = Host.objects.get(name=hostname).get_proc(proc_name)
    proc.restart()
```

**views.py**

```
def call():
    procs = get_procs()
    tasks.swarm_restart.delay(procs)
```

The error I'm getting:
`TypeError: group_restart() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

I am doing something wrong, any lights ?

BTW. celery==3.0.25, django-celery==3.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your `swarm_restart` task, you are chaining `group_restart` tasks. Here, the first task in the chain will execute fine but the the second task will throw error.

> TypeError: group_restart() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Because, the result of first task is passed as an argument to it. The same happens with the next tasks in the chain also.

For example,

```
from celery import task, chain

@app.task
def t1():
    return 't1'

@app.task
def t2():
   return 't2'

wrong_chain = chain( t1.s(), t2.s() )
```

If you execute `wrong_chain` it throughs the similar error even though you are not passing any arguments to `t2`

So, you have to change your work flow depending what you have to do.

Comment: You can replace your `task.s()` with `task.si()` which makes signature immutable and everything works fine with current workflow itself.